# Postfix send only server setup returns nothing

Tags: php, smtp, ubuntu-16.04, postfix-mta

I am *attempting* to create a mail server on my linux machine to act as a send only email server, eventually to be integrated with PHP on my web server.

Unfortunutely, I have been unsuccessful no matter what mail server I use. Right now, i'm working on postfix. I got it installed and configured according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial.

Before I explain my problem here is my config file:

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ns526169.ip-198-100-148.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.example.com, example.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

So, I went to test the smtp server with this console command:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" *my email*
```

I run the command, and nothing happens. The command returns nothing, and I don't get an email. The email I was testing with is a gmail account. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should see something in /var/log/mail.log who explain what appened with your email.

Postfix conf seem correct ans it's normal if your mail command return nothing.

The hostname ns526169.ip-198-100-148.net could be a problem because it's not a real domain name with reverse and MX records.